# Is it possible to lock the memory tray on an iMac 27" (late 2012)?

Tags: imac

After countless searches, I haven't managed to find any clear answer on the subject.

The iMac 27" (late 2012) features a tray on the back of the computer, which you can open after pushing a button located behind the power cable, in order to add or remove memory modules.

We are intending to house a large number of iMac available to a large number of people, we'd rather not get the RAM stolen in the process.

I have an untested theory that the Kensington slot featured on the iMac might lock the button if there is a Kensington lock in place.

Any truth to it or should I be looking into something else?

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this yesterday on cultofmac.com which basically answered all my problems "Maclocks.com comes up with the only solution to fully protect your new iMac" http://www.cultofmac.com/235129/maclocks-lock-for-imac-prevents-your-ram-from-being-stolen-for-just-50/

Here is the link to the product page itself http://www.maclocks.com/imac-locks/imac-security-cable-lock.html

Thanks for bringing awareness to this issue and thanks to maclocks for solving it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Kensington lock to test with, but based on my examination of the RAM slots on my late-2012 iMac, and some Googling, I don't think the lock slot in any way prevents opening the RAM bay. I think you're going to have to come up with some other measure to prevent access.